# Country selection / country-specific menu

Tags: menus, conditional-content

Client makes a malaria drug and it has a few pages that are for specific countries only that will be rather boring for a user to select again and again that they want to see e.g. the information for the US (as opposed to UK, Europe or rest of world.)

Ideal scenario is user sees immediate options to choose US / UK / Europe or Rest of world and then the site is formed based on that choice. Site is less than 20 pages including country variants.

What's the best way (and ideally cheapest, easiest) to achieve something like this? Don't mind using a conditional menu plugin where I can state e.g. this page is US only but I could do with e.g. flags on the top so people with VPNs on or wish to look at other country's info can do so. I don't have a developer so looking at plugins or things I can do. Thanks!

Comment: this is a programming stack, can you edit out the request for plugins? Recommendations are offtopic here, if you need a software recommendation please ask on the software recommendations stack instead. Also look at WP multisite, a core feature that lets you host multiple sites on the same install in either subdomains or subdirectories